# d3.js iterate order changes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

As project to get to know d3.js, I’m displaying tweets on a map in real-time. Everything has worked this far, and I’m very, very pleased with the library.

On the page, I’m trying to list all languages. On hover, I want all tweets of that language to pop up. All of this is done, except some items in the list pops up the tweets of another language. A wrong one, I might add.

This is how I project the dots on the map:

```
points.selectAll('circle')
    .data(tweets)

    .enter()
    .append('circle')

    // Attach node to tweet, so I can use refer to the nodes later
    .each(function(d) {
        d.node = this;
    })

    .attr('r', 1);
```

This is how I create the list:

```
var data = d3.nest()

    // Group by language code
    .key(function(d) { return d.lang.code; })
    .entries(tweets)

    // Sort list by amount of tweets in that language
    .sort(function(a, b) {
        return b.values.length - a.values.length;
    });


var items = languages_dom

    // Add items
    .selectAll('li')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('li');

    // Used for debugging
    .attr('data-lang', function(d) {
        return d.key; // Group key = language code
    })

    // Set text
    .text(function(d) {
        var dt = d.values[0];
        return dt.lang.name;
    })

    // Mouseover handler
    .on('mouseover', function(d) {

        // Compare attribute with 
        // These values are actually different
        var attr = d3.select(this).attr('data-lang');
        console.log(attr, d.key);

        // Pop up each node
        d.values.forEach(function(d) {
            d = d3.select(d.node);

            d.transition()
                .duration(200)
                .attr('opacity', 0.5)
                .attr('r', 8);
        });
    });
```

Note that the script above is run several times. `d.key` refers to another value later in the chain, while I’m not modifying data in that chain.

---

## Edit 22:08

Things seems to work fine when I’m not sorting the data. At least it’s a lead.

Comment: It looks like you're overwriting the data here: `d = d3.select(d.node);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the data changed, the old data seems to be kept somehow.

Either way, I simply deleted the list before applying the new data:

```
languages_dom
    .selectAll('li')
    .remove();
```

Can’t say this is graceful, nor performant, but it gets the job done :)

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, you're overwriting d in your forEach function. Instead, you should try something like

```
    d.values.forEach(function(p) {
        d3.select(p.node)
            .transition()
            .duration(200)
            .attr('opacity', 0.5)
            .attr('r', 8);
    });
```

Notice the forEach variable is named p instead of d.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Tried that, but it didn’t work. The `console.log` in the event handler still shows inconsistent results.